# iOS Development: How can I make my view transition to the right instead of to the default left?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I was wondering if it's possible to make a view transition in from the left to the right.  Similar to the transition that occurs when you pop a view controller off the nav stack, only I want the transition to occur when I push a view controller onto the stack.  The solutions I've found on the net are difficult to follow as a newcomer and it looks like they're trying to accomplish more than what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Is this wise? It'll just be weird for those people who are used to the "standard" transition. (User interfaces should always do what's expected of them, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to decide what kind of transition is best, depending on your application. Just remember to follows the Human Interface Guidelines. Anyway, you can easily accomplish this by using a `CATransition`. Take a look at the documentation and download this Apple sample code, aptly named [View Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html) to start with. Note that this is not the way to go if you want to push a new controller on the stack: this is the way to transition between two arbitrary views.